# RSpec: Can I disable certain shared examples tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using `shared_examples` in RSpec to run a group of tests for multiple upload formats such as yml, csv, etc. for many different rspec files. However, one of my rspec tests that are running these shared examples, does not support csv upload formats. Is it possible to disable/skip certain csv tests in the shared examples for this one rspec file?

Comment: A better solution might be to restructure the tests. Can you give us a sample of how they're structured?

Comment: So I have many controller tests that test uploading files. So in my shared examples 'testing upload formats': I have testing correctly formatted yml/csv/xls, testing incorrectly formatted yml/csv/xls, etc. All the other controllers support all three formats except one controller, who doesn't support csv. Because of this, I don't want to rewrite all the yml and xls tests just for my this one controller so I want to utilize the shared examples tests except the csv tests. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Are the shared examples for yaml, csv, and xls all very similar? Or are they very distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add the allowed upload formats to your controller and have the tests introspect your controllers. This will likely DRY up both the production and test code.

```
class ApplicationController
  def self.upload_formats
    [:yaml, :json, :csv]
  end
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  def self.upload_formats
    [:yaml, :json]
  end
end

shared_examples 'it accepts uploads' do
  let(:formats) { described_class.upload_formats }

  ...
end
```

This might be too DRY; if `self.upload_formats` is missing a format the tests will not catch it.

---

You could add a flag to the shared examples and pass in which formats it should check. If the test for each format is similar, this becomes a simple loop.

```
shared_examples 'it accepts uploads' do |formats: [:yaml, :json, :csv]|
  formats.each do |format|
    let(:format) { format }

    context "in #{format}" do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Most tests will remain unmodified and use the defaults.

```
it_behaves like 'it accepts uploads'
```

Your exceptions can specify their formats.

```
it_behaves like 'it accepts uploads', formats: [:yaml, :json]
```

---

If it's more complicated than that, you may wish to break the shared test down into a separate test for each format. The original shared test runs all the individual shared tests. The outliers can pick and choose.

```
shared_examples 'it accepts uploads in all formats' do
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts yaml uploads'
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts json uploads'
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts csv uploads'
end
```

Again, most tests remain the same.

```
it_behaves_like 'it accepts uploads in all formats'
```

And the outliers can run tests individually.

```
it_behaves_like 'it accepts yaml uploads'
it_behaves_like 'it accepts json uploads'
```

This has the additional advantages of breaking up what might be a large shared example, and allowing individual shared examples to be further customized.

---

And you can combine the two for convenience.

```
shared_examples 'it accepts uploads' do |formats: [:yaml, :json, :csv]|
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts yaml uploads' if formats.include?(:yaml)
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts json uploads' if formats.include?(:json)
  it_behaves_like 'it accepts csv uploads'  if formats.include?(:csv)
end
```